# Only fetch data onMount and not on onActivated when using KeepAlive with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am trying to prevent my child component from fetching data if it is being loaded from cache through KeepAlive.

Is there a better way to fetch data only on first mount and not each time the component is reloaded form the cache?

Parent Component:

```
<KeepAlive>
    <NavigationSub :requestUrl="`/api/competitions?country=${id}`"/>
</KeepAlive>
```

Child Component:

```
<template>
    <NavigationSubItem v-for="item in items" />
    <div v-if="error">
        <button @click.prevent="refresh()">refresh</button>
    </div>
    <Loading v-if="pending" />
</template>
    
<script setup>
    import { hash } from 'ohash';
    
    const props = defineProps({
        requestUrl: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
    });
    
    const {
        data: items,
        pending,
        error,
        refresh,
    } = await useLazyFetch(() => props.requestUrl, {
        key: hash(props.requestUrl),
        server: false,
        mode: 'no-cors',
    });
</script>
```

Comment: On one hand, you are saying that you are not using, KeepAlive but your code has KeepAlive, and where is v-show? Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: The code is what i'm trying to move to, using keepalive rather than just keeping the component in the dom with v-show. I have removed from question to void confusion.

Comment: Maybe it’s as simple as a guard clause to   check if data exists and already has a value. But I don’t know best practices so was unsure if there was a better pattern for this.

Comment: What's the question here? You have it working as expected with the `onMounted` technic and you want to know if "there a better way"? If so, the anwser is no, this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Perhaps a key element to this problem is how `id` is being generated/stored in the parent component. The child component looks fine to me in your code but if that `id` value in the parent is reactive and something is causing it to be re-generated (even if to the same value) it will update the prop and force `NavigationSub` to re-render regardless of cache.